# What preparation of the substrate needs to be done after removing a tile and prior to installing the new tile

Tags: bathroom, tiling

A contractor really made a mess of our bathroom installation, and we are now trying to correct it.

Any advice as to the following procedure would be very much appreciated:

1. the old tile is removed, and all the old adhesive under is also be removed
2. a slurry of base coat( a primer which is cement based) and a bonding liquid mixed in the ration 5 kg base coat : 2,5 Lt bonding liquid, is applied.
3. wait 24 hours
4. apply adhesive and stick on the tiles. Carefully wipe away excess adhesive from the spaces between the tiles and the surfaces of the tiles
5. wait 24 hours
6. Apply grout
7. wait 2 hours - allow grout to set
8. wipe away excess grout
9. wait 24 hours
10. Apply grout sealer

Comment: What is the subfloor made of? That may determine whether your step 2 is necessary. What kind of "adhesive" in step 4?

Comment: I was wondering adhesive? In a bathroom? Thinset with an add mix possibility?  I don’t use adhesives in wet areas as most don’t hold up well to moisture but thinset mortar , sure.

Comment: Just to clarify - floor tile or wall tile?

Answer (score 1):

I think your "slurry mix" is a floor leveler? Is that corect? Your pouring a slurry to level the floor. That would be the correct procedure to prepare a rough surface for tile

After it hardens tile installation can begin. You want to use a thin set adhesive to bond the tile to the surface. Thin set is mixed with water and /or an acrylic admixture (for resiliency) than troweled (notched). Tiles are pressed and set accordingly. Wipe away any squeezed-out thin set with a damp sponge.

When troweling grout into joints do so at a 45 degree angle to the
tile joint. work 3' x 3' areas (or whatever is comfortable). Wait for the grout to stiffen or when you wipe a moistened sponge across the grout joint it stays in place. Rinse frequently and wipe gently.

When you see a haze develop on the tile surface you need to wipe it with a dry rag or cheese cloth. Don't let it sit or it will be a real problem to remove.

That's the short answer on tile installation. It's more difficult than it looks and is best to have someone who's knowledgeable with installing it to be present.